# How to use Zend\Config (application wide variables)

Tags: global-variables, zend-framework2, zend-config

Main question is self explanatory, but I'll give some side examples:

- I'm having trouble figuring out databases, though it seems I can work out config with ServiceManager stuff
- I want to use constants for cookie names, so I can change them easily if there are collisions. Current, I'm calling `$config = new \Zend\Config\Config(include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../config.php');` every time I want access to my global config.php file. A lot of previous solutions were in Zend 1 (eg Zend_Registry). Is this the right way to do it? It seems a little unwieldy using that over and over.
- Is there a way to utilize a Module's configuration file to set module-wide-variables/constants?
- Unless I'm completely missing it, there's no application.ini in Zend 2
- Storing recaptcha public/private keys
- I'm also using my config file for session-variables (same idea as `$_SESSION[CONST_NAME]`), which makes it really clumsy with the config file above. Is it better to hardcode the session names? Like:

---

```
$container = new Zend\Session\Container('auth');
$container->offsetSet('user', $user);
... // instead of 
$container = new Zend\Zession\Container($config['auth']['containername']);
$container->offsetSet($config['auth']['user'], $user);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 module share variables between controllers onBootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128085/zend-framework-2-module-share-variables-between-controllers-onbootstrap)

Comment: Don't use the session for such things, that's not the purpose of the session!

Comment: @markus-tharkun what should I use then? I remember in one of the big "how to login user" (can't find the exact threads) on SO it said to use sessions, unless I completely misunderstood

Comment: Yes, that's right. Some data of the associated user is totally fine to store in the session... I was under the impression it was more but I was wrong.

Comment: What confused me is that you have a $config-auth-user field, the config shouldn't contain user information.

Comment: $config['auth']['user'] only stores the name/key $user is stored under

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All configuration from each `module.config.php` or `Module.php` are put together into a big pot. You can easily access those via `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('config')`

When it comes down to constants, they should be placed inside the respective classes. Like

```
class UserStorage {
    const SESSIONCONTAINERNAME = 'blubbusersession';
}
```

That way you can call `\My\User\Model\UserStorage::SESSIONCONTAINERNAME` whenever you need this info

As far as your example is concerned thought, there should be almost no need to `var-code` your session-container-name because the information from your modules session-data should be made available via your modules `Service-Classes`. But if you still need it, see aboves example.

Furthermore i think it may be a good idea for you to check out how [`zf-commons\ZfcUser`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) does things

Comment: It seems it compiles from global.php and local.php files too (set in `root/config/autoload.config.php')

Comment: And btw, I have numerous other questions. I work through them for at least a day before asking (usually an new approach comes up overnight), but mostly it seems there's a lot of support (previous questions) for Zend 1, but not Zend 2. Stuff like how to elegantly pass data to the layout (again, I found a clumsy solution) and how to check if an action was forwarded. Because these are not previously-asked questions for zend 2, is it alright to ask them all here? Like I should figure it out in the long run, but it'd save me a lot of time, and possibly future users some time

Comment: First you are right. ALL Config-Files are merged together ultimately. And of course you may ask it all here. Someones gotta do the job of asking questions ^^

Comment: Alright, I didn't want to sound like I hadn't tried anything, because I still have a lot of questions! Stay tuned for more xD

Comment: Also, try not to mix options from one module into another one. Keep them strictly separated. And for re-usability of options and to have them directly casted to the correct type, try to make an `Options` class. Check the class here: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/Options/ModuleOptions.php and the factory here: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/Module.php#L90-L93

Comment: const UPLOAD_PATH = getcwd() . '/public/uploads/'; why this is generating error?

Comment: @anil you can't use functions like `getcwd()` when assigning class constants

Comment: @Sam Thank you! I was not aware with this.