# zend framework 2 constants

Tags: php, zend-framework2, constants

I have to declare constants which are available anywhere in application.
In Zend Framework 1 we used to declare in `application.ini` as :

```
constants.NAME_TITLE = "User Name",
```

Where and how do we do this in Zend Framework 2 ?

Comment: What use do these constants have? Where to use them?

Comment: How would you do it without a framework? If only there was a function that let you `define` constants.

Comment: @Sam These constants are to define global variables which I set in configuration for ex. LINK_TO_SOAP_SERVICE , their values are different for different environments. So I set them at one place and use them in entire project.

Comment: @Crisp : I can do it with a define() in php , but I wanted to follow the recommended way if there is in zend framework 2 as there was in zend framework 1

Answer (score 9):

I have found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177163/how-to-use-zend-config-application-wide-variables). You have to create storage class in Model. In that class you can create as many constants as you want.

```
<?php  
namespace Application\Model;
class Application {
    const EMAIL = 'email@gmail.com';
}
```

Now it can be accessed everywhere by:

```
NameOfModule\Model\NameOfModel::NAMEOFCONSTANT
```

So you can for example print the constant in a view like this:

```
<?php echo Application\Model\Application::EMAIL; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm also placing arrays in there by serializing them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays
Reduces a lot of duplicated code in your modules!

Comment: const UPLOAD_PATH = getcwd() . '/public/uploads/'; why this is generating error?

Answer (score 2):

For Zend Framework 2, one alternative solution.

you can define your global variable inside config/autoload/local.php

```
 'array_name' => array(
      'variable_name' => value,
 ),
```

and use it anywhere just like :

```html
$this->config = $obj->getServiceLocator()->get('config'); //create config object
$this->you_variable = $this->config['arrayname']['variable_name']; // fetch value
echo $this->you_variable; // print value
```

Comment: what is $obj ? don't you think it will give error ?

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.4 or higher, you can do it in 1 line, like so: `echo $obj->getServiceLocator()->get('config')['arrayname']['variable_name'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can also write function and variable that can be accessed any where of your application like controller,model and views.

```
<?php  
namespace Webapp;

class ControllerName
   {
        const EMAIL     = 'email@gmail.com';

        public static function myFunction()
          {
             echo "doing work well.";
          }
    }
```

and you can access this class function and property like

```
<?php echo Webapp\ControllerName::EMAIL; ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo Webapp\ControllerName::myFunction(); ?>
```

Comment: What you said is technically correct. For sake of clarification, normally no one should put constants and static methods in a controller (unless if it's a rare case where they can belong nowhere except in that controller)

Answer (score 0):

You can define, assign and access CONSTANT as follows:
Use these two classes with alias:

```
use Zend\Config\Config as Zend_Config;
use Zend\Config\Processor\Constant as Zend_Constant;
```

And then use below code to your any function of the controller class:

```
define ('TEST_CONST', 'bar');
// set true to Zend\Config\Config to allow modifications
$config = new Zend_Config(array('foo' => 'TEST_CONST'), true);
$processor = new Zend_Constant();
$processor->process($config);
echo $config->foo;
```

It will give o/p:

```
bar
```